# Manual outputcache refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache, outputcache, varybyparam

Right now I have OutCache on an action with duration set to 365 days. However depending on some events I would like to clear the cache and there are multiple conditions for clearing cache. Moreover, VaryByParam is not an option.

How can I achieve this?

I think I can do something like this, store a variable in cookie like: RefreshCache = false and check this in VaryByCustom override method. Incase the RefreshCache evaluates to true, reset it to false, increment VaryByCustom argument variable by 1.

However, I am not sure this is an efficient method to achieve what I want.

Comment: Hi, did you maybe figure out how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the output cache item using [HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.removeoutputcacheitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, this will only apply to OuputCache items stored on the server. If you're caching on the client then this method will have no affect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By default it is stored in 3 locations right? web server, any proxy servers, and the user's browser. So how will RemoveOutputCacheItem work given the default scenario? 

Moreover, what do think of the method I proposed?